# Bitmap create out of memory

Tags: java, android, bitmap, out-of-memory

I am trying rotate taken image in `onActivityResult()` from camera Intent, but I am getting Out of memory errors occasionally.

How can I optimize this code?

http://pastebin.com/ieaHS8qB

```
bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, null);
correctBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, bmp.getWidth(), 
                bmp.getHeight(), mat, true);
```

I was trying to add `bmp.recycle()` and `correctBmp.recycle()` after these lines, but it didn't help.

Comment: Don't just link to code externally: add **relevant** pieces of code directly into your post - and link to the whole code if you still believe it's necessary.

Comment: You need to make the picture a little but smaller, try to look for `inSampleSize`

Comment: Better to resampled bitmap as necessary that fit into screen. try to looks this http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: My answer posted in another similar thread might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object/18544069#18544069

Answer (score 2):

if you develope your application api level 10+ you can add your manifest this

```
 android:largeHeap="true" //add this entity.
```

like

```
  <application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
```

or try this (Create Class)

```
   public Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
        int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth,
            reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}

public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
        int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
        if (width > height) {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
        } else {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);
        }
    }
    return inSampleSize;
}
```

thanks to that code you can also resize your bitmap.

Comment: Adding "largeHeap" to the manifest is not a good practice until it is really really required.

Answer (score 1):

try to add below code before decodestream and pass option as a parameter.

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();                
options.inSampleSize = 5;               
options.inPurgeable = true;             
options.inInputShareable = true;


bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null, options);
```

Comment: Create options to help use less memory, if you want you cann add options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565; also